# What is this ring-shaped pastry called?

Tags: image-identification

[image: ring-shaped cookies]

Are these pretzels? Or how can I name it correctly in English?

Comment: are they bread stick texture but in rings?

Comment: As a native English speaker, I would still have to look at the package to figure out what those are.  Without a package, if I needed to point them out, I'd probably just say "rings", counting on there not being other types of ring-shaped things besides these.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the telltale signs of salt that pretzels would have, so my guess is that they are [**dry bread rings**](http://www.foodlatvia.com/product/milk-dry-breadrings):

[image: dry bread rings]

---

But there *are* pretzels that are shaped like this. They are called **pretzel rings**:

[image: pretzel rings]

Answer (score 0):

I think, generally, they would be called [**bagels**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagel) or, if you want to be more specific, I guess you can call them **Russian bagels**. I know in the Russian language they are called **baranki** or [**sushki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sushki), but I don't think there is an exact equivalent English term for this type of pastry other than referring to them as either bagels or sushki. I think there is nothing wrong with saying **sushki** and then explaining what type of food you're talking about exactly. For example:

> When I was living in Russia, I was eating **sushki** everyday. **Sushki** are a type of pastry that looks similar to our American bagels. The only difference is that they're smaller and harder than bagels.

By the way, I'm not a food expert. That's just the way I would explain it if somebody asked me what those are.

Comment: The scale is hard to be sure of, but they look like they have far too large a hole for bagels, and are probably too small besides. (Russian bagels appear from a quick search to be of similar size and shape to any other; they are merely baked with rye or pumpernickel.)